# Enabling a input control with drop-down list selection

Tags: javascript, html

Before writing this, I looked, edited and tried all scripts on this topic, but none of them worked because I'm a very new to HTML and Javascript. I also didn't understand what was wrong.

I'll briefly explain: I must activate Javascript via an input number type trough the selection of a determined value or option in a select field.

```js
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function enableInput(){
        /*alert("works!");*/
        if (document.getElementById("roof_type").selectedIndex == "0") {
            document.getElementById("gables").disable=true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("gables").disable=false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Calc the quote</title>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
         function enableInput(){
          /*alert("works!");*/
          if (document.getElementById("roof_type").selectedIndex == "0") {
                 document.getElementById("gables").disable=true;
             } else {
                  document.getElementById("gables").disable=false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="enableInput();">
        <form="quote">
            <table >
                <tr>
                   <td>
                <div align="center">
                         Input the roof type: <br />
                 </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>
                        <div align="center">
                           <select id="roof_type"name="roof_type" onChange="enableInput();">
                                <option value=gable_roof selected="selected">with Gables</option>
                                <option value=round_roof>Rounded</option>
                             <option value=flat_roof>Flat / Plain</option>
                           </select><br />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div align="center">
                                   input the gables'number: <br />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div align="center">
                                <input id="gables" name="gables" type="number" min="1"  step="1" value="1" disabled="disabled" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually changing `disabled` property, use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and 
[`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/https:):

```
function enableInput() {
    if (document.getElementById("roof_type").selectedIndex === 0) {
       document.getElementById("gables").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
    } else {
       document.getElementById("gables").removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
}
```